# Fast way to compare items in list with each other for similarity in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, string-comparison

I am aware of the other questions about comparing items (strings) with each other, but I didn't fing any which will solve my problem.

I'm trying to do a text analysis of scientific papers (titles, keywords, abstracts). I want to count the occurrence of words in text. The code functions fine, but I've got problem with one part - comparing strings in list for similarity. There are lot of words like ex. "wetland" and "wetlands" and my code is comparing them for similarity and replacing them with the first one ("wetlands" become "wetland").

It works as I need but it's quite slow. So my question is if there is some better solution for this.

My code:

```
def similar_words(words_list):
    checked_words = []
    similar = words_list
    ind_a = 0
    num_words = len(words_list)
    print("from" + " " + str(num_words) + " " + "words")
    for similar[ind_a] in similar:
        if similar[ind_a] not in checked_words:
            ind_b = 0
            for word in similar:
                match = SequenceMatcher(None, similar[ind_a], similar[ind_b]).ratio()
                if match >= 0.85:
                    similar[ind_b] = similar[ind_a]
                ind_b += 1
            ind_a += 1
        checked_words.append(similar[ind_a])
        stdout.write("\r%d words solved" % ind_a)
        stdout.flush()
    stdout.write("\n")
    print("solved %d words for 85percent similarity" % num_words)
    return similar
```

Comment: This is a good place to visit: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `checked_words = []` I'd start by making this into a `set()`. The `in similar` lookups are probably also expensive, depending on the type of `wordlist`. `for similar[ind_a] in similar` really looks weird, it re-assigns the value at the index while iterating over the list.

Answer (score 2):

The [Python Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) has [tools for *stemming* and *lemmatization*](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-iv-stemming-and-lemmatization). It probably performs better than your code (and prevents a lot of "reinventing the wheel")

Comment: I know NLTK and already tried it (lemmatization - stemming is useless for this), but I was somehow disappointed with the results (it changes the words a lot). That's why I'm trying to reinvent the wheel because wheels are not all the same.. But maybe I'll give it a second try.